# Odd function pointer warning in C

Tags: c

`ueach` is a function that loops through a Unicode string, and running the callback on each character by passing a single-character string to it.

```
string ueach(string s, void *function(string)) {
    unsigned long i;
    for (i = 0; i < s.length; i++)
        function(uchar(s, i));
}
```

If I have a callback `testing`:

```
void testing(string c) {
    puts(utoc(c));
}
```

which prints the given character (`utoc` converts Unicode string to a UTF-8 `char *`) it all works fine. The code used:

```
string a = ctou("Hello, world!");
ueach(a, &testing);
```

However, I get this warning:

```
test.c: In function ‘main’:
test.c:8: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘ueach’ from incompatible pointer type
ulib:171: note: expected ‘void * (*)(struct string)’ but argument is of type ‘void (*)(struct string)’
```

If I put parentheses around the function part of the `ueach` prototype like this:

```
string ueach(string s, void (*function)(string)) { ... }
```

then it works just fine as well, with no warning.

What is the difference between `void * (*)(struct string)` and `void (*)(struct string)`?

What is the difference between `void *function(string)` and `void (*function)(string)`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- `void * (*)(struct string)` - pointer to a function returning a `void *`.
- `void (*)(struct string)` - pointer to function returning `void`.
- `void *function(string)` - function returning a `void *`
- `void (*function)(string)` - pointer to function returning `void`

The third decays to the first, because:

> "except when it is the operand of the
>   sizeof operator or the unary `&`
>   operator, a function designator with
>   type 'function returning type' is
>   converted to an expression that has
>   type 'pointer to function returning
>   type'."

C99 §6.3.2.1/4

Answer (score 3):

It's just a matter of operator precedence.  In the error case, the compiler parses it as a function returning a void*, (a pointer to something), rather than a pointer to a function returning void.